# How to apply a Gaussian Blur using theano

Tags: python, theano

I am not being able to understand `theano` `conv2D` function I want to blur a set of images with a Gaussian kernel:

```
sigma = 10
size = int(6*sigma+1) if int(6*sigma+1)%2 else int(6*sigma) #61 when sigma = 10
k = int(size/2) 
images = mpimg.imread('Lenna.png') #512x512x3

#Use openCV to compare with a working implementation
blurred_lena = cv2.GaussianBlur(images, (size,size), sigma)
plt.imshow(blurred_lena)
plt.show()

#Use theano
images = images.transpose(2,0,1) 
x = np.arange(-k,k+1)
y = np.arange(-k,k+1)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
M = T.ftensor3()
Gv=np.exp(-(X**2+Y**2)/(2*sigma**2))
Gv=(Gv/np.sum(Gv.reshape(-1))).astype(np.float32)
G_kernel = theano.shared(Gv)

R2 = conv2d(M,G_kernel)
conv = theano.function(
    inputs=[M],
    outputs=R2,
)

res = conv(images)
res = res.transpose(1,2,0)
plt.figure(2)
plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()
```

The above code doesn't work it gives the error:

```
Error allocating 595360000 bytes of device memory (out of memory). Driver report 394424320 bytes free and 1072889856 bytes total 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/joao/Dropbox/physological/Juggler/SaliencyExp/conv.py", line 50, in <module>
    res = conv(images)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 610, in __call__
    storage_map=self.fn.storage_map)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 599, in __call__
    outputs = self.fn()
RuntimeError: GpuCorrMM failed to allocate working memory of 625 x 238144

Apply node that caused the error: GpuCorrMM{valid, (1, 1)}(GpuContiguous.0, GpuContiguous.0)
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (False, True, False, False)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, True, False, False))]
Inputs shapes: [(3, 1, 512, 512), (1, 1, 25, 25)]
Inputs strides: [(262144, 0, 512, 1), (0, 0, 25, 1)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Either way since the gaussian filter is separable I would rather apply two linear filters one in the `x` and one in the `y` of the images. But I don't understand how to pull this off and the documentation of [conv2d](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d) is not helping me much.

Answer (score 3):

Your filter is bigger than your input image. conv2d cannot handle this situation when `border_mode='valid'`, which is the default border mode.

Why? Because the valid region of your image has the size 1 x 1 x 37 x -2. Negative dimensions make no sense.

Solution: use `R2 = conv2d(M,G_kernel,border_mode='full')`

As for the second part of the question, you can use the seperated kernels using `R2 = conv2d(conv2d(M,G_x_kernel,border_mode='full'),G_y_kernel,border_mode='full')`
However, I'm not sure it will increase speed with these small filters and running on a GPU.

Comment: sorry I had posted the wrong error. The error I get is that I cannot allocate so much memory that's why I wanted to use linear kernels as well. Your G_x_kernel shape is 1xk and the G_y_kernel is kx1 ?

Comment: The weird thing is, there should be absolutely no reason to use such a large chunk of memory. With the input shapes Inputs shapes: [(3, 1, 512, 512), (1, 1, 25, 25)] you don't need 625 x 238144 bytes of memory.
Me thinks he is convoluting the wrong dimensions and that it is interpreting your data as 512x512 images of 3x1 pixels big, which it is convoluting with a 25x25 filter, to result in a lot of images 25x25 big. Which of course don't fit memory.

Comment: Exactly and I tried to do R2 = conv2d(M,G_kernel,image_shape=images.shape) just to tell him whats the right dimensions of the image and he doesn't get it. In the documentation it says that the argument images_shape is a (tuple of length 2 or 3) – ([number images,] image height, image width)

Answer (score 1):

The pixel dimensions need to be the last dimensions for convolutions in Theano (because those convolutions are usually used for neural nets, not images). In theano, the convention for these feature maps is (batch_size, image channels, x, y). So instead of

```
images = mpimg.imread('Lenna.png')
```

try

```
images = np.rollaxis(mpimg.imread('Lenna.png'), 2, 0)
```

To convert your image to 3x512x512 instead of 512x512x3.

Comment: I am already doing that with the line: images = images.transpose(2,0,1)